# Xamarin.Androdid expandable notification

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

i'm following this link for create a notification: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications

this is my code:

```
Notification.BigTextStyle textStyle = new Notification.BigTextStyle();

            // Fill it with text:
            string longTextMessage = "I went up one pair of stairs.";
            longTextMessage += " / Just like me. ";
            //...
            textStyle.BigText(longTextMessage);

            // Set the summary text:
            textStyle.SetSummaryText("The summary text goes here.");

            // Plug this style into the builder:


            //creo la notifica:
            var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(instance, "enter")
                          .SetSmallIcon(global::Android.Resource.Drawable.IcDialogInfo)
                          .SetContentIntent( pending)
                          .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.Sound)
                          .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate)
                          .SetNumber(count)
                          .SetAutoCancel(true)
                          .SetContentTitle("Proximity") // Set the title
                          .SetContentText($"benvenuto nel beacon di colore {deskOwner},{count}")
                          .SetStyle(textStyle)
                          .Build();
                           count++;
                // Get the notification manager:
                NotificationManager notificationManager = instance.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
                // Pubblico la notifica:
                const int notificationId = 0;
                notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, builder);

            return null;
        }
```

But in .SetStyle(textStyle) gives me this error:
'cannot convert from 'Android.App.Notification.BigTextStyle' to 'Android.Support.V4.App.NotificationCompat.Style'
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The reason it not working is that you are using NotificationCompat but not using NotifcationCompat.BigTextStyle try the below instead:

```
        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle textStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();

        // Fill it with text:
        string longTextMessage = "I went up one pair of stairs.";
        longTextMessage += " / Just like me. ";
        //...
        textStyle.BigText(longTextMessage);

        // Set the summary text:
        textStyle.SetSummaryText("The summary text goes here.");
        // To complete the following is needed : 
        builder.SetStyle(textStyle);
```